# how to get dropdown selected rows from gridview in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am using yii2 advanced framework. There is a select2 dropdown list of companies name.
 In view/companies/index.php

```
Select2::widget([
    'id' => 'front_companies_select',
    'name' => 'state_10',
    'data' => $companyNameList,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select ...',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
]);
```

and a button get info

```
<?= Html::SubmitButton( 'Get info', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-success' , 'id' =>'info']) ?>
```

**here is myjsfile**

```
  $("#getinfo").click(function(){
    var selval = '';
    $("#front_companies_select option:selected").each(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if ($this.length) {
      var selText = $this.val();
      selval = selText+','+selval;
    }
  });
    var searchurl = 'index.php?r=companies&id'+selval;
    window.location.replace(searchurl);
    alert (selval); //here I can get id of selected rows but I want complete row
  });
```

I want to show gridview rows of selected companies.
how to solve this ?

Comment: You can use jQuery to detect what option are selected and pass it to a gridview

Comment: @Sfili_81  I use jquery .. but it is only giving id... how to get complete row

Comment: Add jquery code at the question so we can see why you get only the id

Comment: @Sfili_81 edited the question...

Comment: var selText = $this.text();

Comment: It gives text of only one column .. means only name... not whole row @Sfili_81

Comment: one row for me means, some element's from onecompany  model given by id, so when i select an element i'll make a jquery ajax call to retrieve the model. This is one solution. Another solution but it's not very beautiful, when you retrieve the id by jquery you can find a row wich, for example, has data-id="your id" and get all values of this row

Answer (score 1):

you can write on click jquery function for #info and get select2 box user selected values after that you can get current url bind selected values to url that url pass seachmodel values

```
$('#info'),on('click',function(){
var selval = '';
$("#front_companies_select option:selected").each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.length) {
    var selText = $this.val();
    selval = selText+','+selval;
   }
});
var searchurl = 'someurl&searchvalues'+selval;
window.location.replace(searchurl);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in _form just put your field and table:-

```js
     <?= $form->field($model, 'your_field')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' => arrayhelper::map(your_table::find()->all(),'id','your_field'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
        ],
    ]); ?>
```